# populating db frm rss xml

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, xml

I want to read rss from different sources and populate them in the database (sqlserver 2008). I'm planning to store the content of rss.xml in one table and the master information like the version and deep link of the rss in another table. I haven't worked in xml before and couldn't find a better solution till now... help anybody...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrote a feed crawler to crawl through every feed in feed list and populate the db accordingly...